# How do I enable dynamic favicons in a custom theme?

Tags: 8

So, I'm working on a site that I didn't build and I'm trying to figure out how to get the favicons working. The site has favicons enabled in the theme settings folder as well as through the themes settings UI, however no favicons are showing up. From what I read, this should just be a question of putting the favicon in the theme root folder. The issue is that I have a bunch of favicons that are meant to be served dynamically (e.g. different devices/sizes, etc) from a subfolder of my theme e.g. `themes/custom/mytheme/assets/images/favicon`. I haven't dug too far into this yet, but I assume that there's a script somewhere that deals with this. So, how or what do I do to enable my favicons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your theme allows for functionality to add further icons you'll need to add head link tags yourself with something like this using template_preprocess_html:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $icon = [
        '#tag' => 'link',
        '#attributes' => [
            'href' => '<url to your icon-52x52.png>',
            'rel' => 'shortcut icon',
            'sizes' => '52x52'
        ],
    ];
    $variables['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
        $icon,
        'icon52x52
    ];
}
```

Or if you want to avoid adding code the metatag module as a sub module of "Metatag: favicons" to allow you to add them from the CMS
https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Comment: The site has the metatag: favicons module, is there any further config needed?

Comment: Yeah you'll need to go to the metatag admin screen and set your images. That's under "Configuration > search and metadata > metatag" then edit the global and there should be favicons and touch icons options in there

Comment: This hook perfectly added an icon, and I deleted the current one in theme_page_attachments_alter.
`
  foreach ($attachments['#attached']['html_head_link'] as $key => $attachment) 
    {
      if (empty($attachment[0]['rel'])) {
        continue;
      }
      elseif ($attachment[0]['rel'] === 'shortcut icon') {
        unset($attachments['#attached']['html_head_link'][$key]);
      }
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to your custom implementation you can use [responsive_favicons](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_favicons) that helps with creating and displaying all the favicons for all platforms correctly without knowing all the details of what goes where or proper names.

Part of the instructions will tell you to to upload a favicon.png (greater than 260px width is recommended) and with a form to fill will generate all icons for you.